# How to create listener for send and receive file using SMACK in android?

Tags: android, openfire, asmack

I want to implement a file transfer functionality in my chat application which I have developed in Android using SMACK and Openfire.But I got an error in sending and receiving a file.So can anybody help me to solve this problem.Thanks In advance.

Here following is a  code for receiving a file.

```
ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        if (sdm == null)
            sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);
        sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");
        sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");
        XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
        // Create the file transfer manager
        final FileTransferManager managerListner = new FileTransferManager(connection);
        FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(connection, true);
        Log.i("File transfere manager", "created");
        managerListner.addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void fileTransferRequest(FileTransferRequest request) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("Recieve File","new file transfere request  new file transfere request   new file transfere request");
                Log.i("file request","from" + request.getRequestor());
                IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();
                Log.i("Recieve File alert dialog", "accepted");
                try {
                    transfer.recieveFile(new File("/mnt/sdcard/" + request.getFileName()));
                    while (!transfer.isDone() || (transfer.getProgress() < 1)) {

                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        Log.i("Recieve File alert dialog", "still receiving : "+ (transfer.getProgress()) + " status "+ transfer.getStatus());
                            if (transfer.getStatus().equals(org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransfer.Status.error)) {
                                // Log.i("Error file",
                                // transfer.getError().getMessage());
                                    Log.i("Recieve File alert dialog",
                                        "cancelling still receiving : "
                                                + (transfer.getProgress())
                                                + " status "
                                                + transfer.getStatus());
                                    transfer.cancel();
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
                }catch (XMPPException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }    
        });
```

Here following is an error Which I have arise.

```
02:48:58 PM RCV  (1079277904): <iq type="error" id="6gQg0-6" to="admin-pc/cc4dd310" from="2222222222@admin-pc/Smack"><si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si" id="jsi_3030055238839806007" profile="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer"><file xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer" name="sdcard"><desc>test</desc></file><feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="form"><field var="stream-method" type="list-single"><option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></option><option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb</value></option></field></x></feature></si><error code="405" type="cancel"><not-allowed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error mostly occurs because you just missed to add the configuration of provider  manager that allows to share files.
please add following static code in to provider manager class

```
// FileTransfer
pm.addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si",new StreamInitiationProvider());
pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams",new BytestreamsProvider());
pm.addIQProvider("open","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new
         OpenIQProvider());
pm.addIQProvider("data","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new
DataPacketProvider());
pm.addIQProvider("close","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new
         CloseIQProvider());
pm.addExtensionProvider("data","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new
         DataPacketProvider());
```

Also add following property to your open fire server to enable file sharing.

```
xmpp.proxy.enabled =true
xmpp.proxy.externalip =your public ip
xmpp.proxy.port  =7777
```

this will work for you.

Comment: Can you explain me what is xmpp.proxy.externalip? In my case I set http://192.168.0.102:9090 as externalip.Is it ok?

Comment: if your server is local then 192.168.0.102 
if it is hosted on web server on internet then the ip of the server.
that is used to map your domain name.
but if you are using it locally then u just go for 192.168.0.102
hope it will be helpful to you .

Comment: Ok Thank you very much Bug for helping me.

Comment: Hey Bug Can you send me a code or file for sending and receiving files?Thanks

Comment: i created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/DevendraSingh91/2f1d7603ec7aba776053). you can check it out. @pragneshsoni